# Issue when view in Landscape mode

Tags: android

When I view the app in landscape mode...it shows like below. Register button is cutting. I just started to learn Android.

[image]

My xml code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bugmanagement.pankaj.androidexample.Activities.UserManagement.Auth.RegisterActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lblEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lblUserName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblEmailAddress"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lblPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblUserName">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lblPasswordConfirmation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblPassword">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPasswordConfirmation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_passwordConfirmation"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblPasswordConfirmation"
        android:text="Register" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNavigateToLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:text="Login" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnNavigateToLogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarRegister" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: make it in a ScrollView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try wrapping your layout in a ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

This will make your layout scrollable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bugmanagement.pankaj.androidexample.Activities.UserManagement.Auth.RegisterActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lblEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lblUserName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblEmailAddress"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lblPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblUserName">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lblPasswordConfirmation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblPassword">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPasswordConfirmation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_passwordConfirmation"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblPasswordConfirmation"
        android:text="Register" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNavigateToLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:text="Login" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnNavigateToLogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarRegister" />

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can u send the correct xml ? It closes app everytime. seems like some issue is coming.

Comment: Thank You very much. Best answer. Upvoted and accepted